# Accessing resources included in python source distribution package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python package, and I've added some files which are needed for the module to function, like this: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files

Due to circumstances, this is the method I need to use, if at all possible. I also need to end up with a source distributable, so something that works when making other types of python distributables doesn't work for me.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1',
      py_modules=['mypackage'],
      install_requires=['numpy'],
      data_files=[('data', ['data/file0.npz', 'data/file1.npz'])]
      )
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
├── PKG-INFO
├── data
│   ├── data0.npz
│   └── data1.npz
├── dist
│   ├── mypackage-0.1.zip
├── mypackage.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── requires.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── mypackage.py
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

I'm trying to load it in like this(every function but **init** removed for simplicity):

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data0 = np.load("data/file0.npz")
        self.data1 = np.load("data/file1.npz")
```

And get this error when trying to instantiate the class:

```
No such file or directory: 'data/file0.npz'
```

What do I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load package resources, I usually use [`pkg_resources` module](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html)

Here is an example to get resource file relative to current module:

```py
from pkg_resources import resource_filename

def main():
    print(resource_filename(__name__, 'data/test.txt'))
```

In your `setup.py` you can use [`package_data`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) to include package data files.

```py
setup(
    name='',
    # (...)
    package_data={
        '': [
            '*.txt',
        ],
    },
)
```

Note: To make it works, `data` has to be a python module.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm trying to load data, which is stored inside the package, from within a class which is part of said package. Isn't what you're describing how I should load data in the package from outside the package?

Comment: No no, my code is loading data from within the same package. Read carefully the documentation of `resource_filename`. The first argument is the package/module from the resource should be loaded. Here I'm using `__name__` which is equivalent to load filename from current package/module.

Comment: Btw, in setup.py (for the packaging part) you could also use `include_package_data` option to automatically include data from your package(s).

Comment: @hellomatey27 could you confirm it answers your question (or not). Kind regards.